# How to get average from json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


function App() {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  **const avg = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length**

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("URL")
      .then((data) => setStudents(data.data.students));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {students.map((student) => (
        <div key={student.id}>
           <p><h3> {student.firstName} {student.lastName}</h3></p>
                <p>{student.email}</p>
                <p>{student.company}</p>
                <p>{student.skill}</p>
               
                <p>{avg(student.grades)}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hello
I put a function to get the average value from the json, but it doesn't work.
I don't know if the function is wrong or the location of the function is wrong.
Can you please help me?

```
const avg = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length
```

```
Above is the json file format.
```

Comment: what does the JSON look like?

Comment: The grades are strings. They should be numbers, or you should convert them to numbers.

Comment: Try const avg = arr => arr.reduce((a,b) => +a + +b, 0) / arr.length and let us know if it makes any difference...

Comment: @SiddharthSeth Thank you for your help. How does the extra + give the correct answer?

Comment: it converts the variable to a number. Specially useful when either a number or a string that evaluates to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your json data, you'll need to convert the grades to numbers before they can be averaged, which can be done with `map` before `reduce`

```
const avg = arr => arr.map(grade => parseInt(grade)).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length
```

Comment: Yes, they need to be converted to numbers, but you don't need an extra loop: `arr.reduce((a,b) => +a + +b, 0) / arr.length`.

Answer (score 0):

This is more suitable

```
const average = arr => (arr.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => parseInt(previousValue) + parseInt(currentValue)) / arr.length) || "Error occured at calculation";
```